# Extract a column from a DataFrame to insert into another one using one column as intersection of both

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to join two different DataFrames, `survival` and `imputed_DF` using the column `numero` as the column that appears in both DataFrames.
The objective is to maintain the whole `imputed_DF` with the column `survived` that appears in `survival` DataFrame. Some rows are going to be empty as some values of `numero` are missing in `survival` DataFrame, in those cases I want to obtain `NaN`.

`survival` DataFrame is the following one:

```
   Tipo de documento  Número de documento    ...     CIUDAD  survived
0                  CC               260037    ...        EPS         0
1                  CC               260037    ...     BOGOTA         1
2                  CC               165182    ...        EPS         1
3                  CC               165182    ...     BOGOTA         1
```

And `imputed_DF` is:

```
   numero          ...           VOLUMEN PLAQUETARIO.
0  21384.0          ...                           10.5
1  30779.0          ...                           10.5
2  42792.0          ...                           10.5
3  53862.0          ...                           10.5
```

My code is:

```
result = pd.merge(imputed_DF, survival, sort=False, on='numero')
```

But I got the grown answer as all values of `survived`column  are `0` and also I loss rows from `imputed_DF` (I lose rows that are not in `survival`DataFrame).
What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Post a [mcve]. You probably will want to set `how='outer'` too

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
result = pd.merge(left=imputed_DF, right=survival[['numero', 'survival']], how='left', on='numero')
```